# Convert Pandas function into a Pyspark function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this following code that I need to convert to Pyspark.

I know how to create the dataframe `df_stack_exchange` in Pyspark but cannot figure out how to create the equivalent **`assign_boxes`** function in Pyspark. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
data_stack_exchange = {'store': ['A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'worker': [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
        'boxes': [105, 90, 100, 80, 10, 200, 70, 210, 50, 0],
        'optimal_boxes': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df_stack_exchange = pandas.DataFrame(data_stack_exchange)

def assign_boxes(s):
    total = s.sum()
    d = min(total // 100, len(s)-1)
    return [100]*d+[total - 100*d]+[0]*(len(s)-d-1)

df['optimal_boxes'] = df.groupby('store')['boxes'].transform(assign_boxes)
```

I've read up on UDFs via official Pyspark documentation and 50+ stackexchange threads but cant figure it out

Comment: This is on AWS but I imagine azure will suffice

Answer (score 0):

The below method works outside a function:

```
w0=Window.partitionBy("store")
sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("row",row_number().over(w0.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",lit("100"))
sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("sum_boxes",sum(col("boxes")).over(w0))

sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",when(col("row")==max(col("row")).over(w0),\
                                           col("sum_boxes")-lag(sum(col("optimal_boxes")).over(w0.orderBy("row"))).over(w0.orderBy("row"))).otherwise(col("optimal_boxes")))
sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",when(col("optimal_boxes").isNull(),col("boxes")).otherwise(col("optimal_boxes")))
sp_df=sp_df.drop("sum_boxes","row")
sp_df.show()
```

if you need a function, the below works. You may want to tweak it a bit to suit your needs:

```
def optimal_boxes(df,group_col,calc_col):
  w0=Window.partitionBy(group_col)
  df=df.withColumn("row",row_number().over(w0.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
  df=df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",lit("100"))
  df=df.withColumn("sum_boxes",sum(col(calc_col)).over(w0))

  df=df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",when(col("row")==max(col("row")).over(w0),\
                                            col("sum_boxes")-lag(sum(col("optimal_boxes")).over(w0.orderBy("row"))).over(w0.orderBy("row"))).otherwise(col("optimal_boxes")))
  df=df.withColumn("optimal_boxes",when(col("optimal_boxes").isNull(),col(calc_col)).otherwise(col("optimal_boxes")))
  df=df.drop("sum_boxes","row")
  return df

sp_df1=optimal_boxes(sp_df,"store","boxes")
sp_df1.show()
```

Below is the output dataframe. It works for store c too.

```
+-----+------+-----+-------------+
|store|worker|boxes|optimal_boxes|
+-----+------+-----+-------------+
|    A|     1|  105|          105|
|    B|     1|   90|          100|
|    B|     2|  100|         90.0|
|    C|     1|   80|          100|
|    C|     2|   10|          100|
|    C|     3|  200|         90.0|
|    D|     1|   70|          100|
|    D|     2|  210|          100|
|    D|     3|   50|          100|
|    D|     4|    0|         30.0|
+-----+------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: I had a similar answer done like this via SQL and partitions but unfortunately it doesnt work for situations like 'Store C' where the sum (280) is less than number of rows * 100 (300). The sums of column 'boxes' and column 'optimal_boxes' will tie out BUT one row will be negative.

I previously spot fixed this via partitions but isnt scalable if the group of stores go past the current size of 4 whereas the Pandas python version is able to account for all store sizes

Appreciate the effort

Comment: @qwerty12, it works for situations such as store c.  try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can use a few tricks to recreate the `assign_boxes` function using pyspark native functions without needing to resort to a udf. We can use groupby and aggregate functions to directly calculate the quantities `total`, `d`, and `len(s)`, then use a combination of `F.array` and `F.repeat` to return the same array that the `assign_boxes` function returns, then explode the array:

```
df_optimal = df.groupby(
    'store'
).agg(
    F.sum('boxes').alias('total'),
    (F.count('*')).alias('count'),
).withColumn(
    'totalFloorDivide100', F.floor(F.col('total') / F.lit(100))
).withColumn(
    'd', F.least('totalFloorDivide100', F.col('count') -1)
).withColumn(
    'optimal_boxes_array', F.concat(
        F.array_repeat(F.lit(100), F.col('d').cast('int')),
        F.array(F.lit(F.col('total') - 100*F.col('d'))),
        F.array_repeat(F.lit(0), F.col('count').cast('int')-F.col('d').cast('int')-1),
    )
).select(
    'store',
    F.explode('optimal_boxes_array').alias('optimal_boxes')
)

+-----+-------------+
|store|optimal_boxes|
+-----+-------------+
|    A|          105|
|    B|          100|
|    B|           90|
|    C|          100|
|    C|          100|
|    C|           90|
|    D|          100|
|    D|          100|
|    D|          100|
|    D|           30|
+-----+-------------+
```

However, this is problematic because pyspark has no concept of an index, so there won't be any way to join this back to the original DataFrame unless we create an index of some kind (we want the optimal_boxes here to be joined back to the original df in the order they are shown).

So to do this, we will replace the line `F.explode(...)` with `F.posexplode('optimal_boxes_array').alias('pos','optimal_boxes')` which creates an index corresponding to each element of the array:

```
+-----+---+-------------+
|store|pos|optimal_boxes|
+-----+---+-------------+
|    A|  0|          105|
|    B|  0|          100|
|    B|  1|           90|
|    C|  0|          100|
|    C|  1|          100|
|    C|  2|           90|
|    D|  0|          100|
|    D|  1|          100|
|    D|  2|          100|
|    D|  3|           30|
+-----+---+-------------+
```

We need to then add the same pos column to the original DataFrame that corresponds to the position within each store (which can be accomplished using a monotonically increasing id and window):

```
window = Window.partitionBy('store').orderBy('id')

df = df.withColumn(
    'id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).select('store','worker','boxes', (rank().over(window) - 1).alias('pos'))

+-----+------+-----+---+
|store|worker|boxes|pos|
+-----+------+-----+---+
|    A|     1|  105|  0|
|    B|     1|   90|  0|
|    B|     2|  100|  1|
|    C|     1|   80|  0|
|    C|     2|   10|  1|
|    C|     3|  200|  2|
|    D|     1|   70|  0|
|    D|     2|  210|  1|
|    D|     3|   50|  2|
|    D|     4|    0|  3|
+-----+------+-----+---+
```

Then we can inner join the two DataFrame together on `['store','pos']`:

```
df.join(df_optimal, on=['store','pos'], how='inner').select(
    'store',
    'worker',
    'boxes',
    'optimal_boxes'
)

+-----+------+-----+-------------+
|store|worker|boxes|optimal_boxes|
+-----+------+-----+-------------+
|    A|     1|  105|          105|
|    B|     1|   90|          100|
|    B|     2|  100|           90|
|    C|     1|   80|          100|
|    C|     2|   10|          100|
|    C|     3|  200|           90|
|    D|     1|   70|          100|
|    D|     2|  210|          100|
|    D|     3|   50|          100|
|    D|     4|    0|           30|
+-----+------+-----+-------------+
```

The fully reproducible code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data_stack_exchange = {'store': ['A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'worker': [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
        'boxes': [105, 90, 100, 80, 10, 200, 70, 210, 50, 0],
        'optimal_boxes': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df_stack_exchange = pd.DataFrame(data_stack_exchange)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_stack_exchange)

df_optimal = df.groupby(
    'store'
).agg(
    F.sum('boxes').alias('total'),
    (F.count('*')).alias('count'),
).withColumn(
    'totalFloorDivide100', F.floor(F.col('total') / F.lit(100))
).withColumn(
    'd', F.least('totalFloorDivide100', F.col('count') -1)
).withColumn(
    'optimal_boxes_array', F.concat(
        F.array_repeat(F.lit(100), F.col('d').cast('int')),
        F.array(F.lit(F.col('total') - 100*F.col('d'))),
        F.array_repeat(F.lit(0), F.col('count').cast('int')-F.col('d').cast('int')-1),
    )
).select(
    'store',
    F.posexplode('optimal_boxes_array').alias('pos','optimal_boxes')
)

window = Window.partitionBy('store').orderBy('id')

df = df.withColumn(
    'id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).select('store','worker','boxes', (rank().over(window) - 1).alias('pos'))

df.join(df_optimal, on=['store','pos'], how='inner').select(
    'store',
    'worker',
    'boxes',
    'optimal_boxes'
)
```

Comment: did this answer end up helping?